# Facebook Login Api Not working inside Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-authentication

I am using facebook web sdk in my angular application, but I keep on getting the following error :-

```
checkLoginState is not defined
```

Facebook Script in my Auth Controller :-

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into this app.';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into Facebook.';
    }
}

function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxxx',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.6'
    });

};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', { locale: 'en_US', fields: 'name, email, id' }, function(response) {
        console.log('Successful login for name: ' + response.name);
        console.log('Successful login for email: ' + response.email);
        console.log('Successful login for id: ' + response.id);
        console.log('Successful login for picture: ' + response.picture);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
            'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
        document.getElementById('pic').innerHTML =
            'Your user id is : ' + response.id + "<br />" +
            "<img src='" + "https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture?type=large' alt='' />";
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is checkLoginSte called?

Comment: checkLoginState needs to `return` something.

Comment: If I put the same script in <script> tag in the HTML page, this works fine, but the problem is when I use inside a controller

Comment: `checkLoginState()` is not a scope method hence is undefined to the ui. Check my answer for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You are following [this web guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) for integrating facebook login to your angular app. They are using the plain javascript in this link.

You should use [this tutorial](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/facebook-authentication-in-your-angularjs-web-app/) instead to integration facebook login/api in your **angular app**. That's the recommended link as mentioned in their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/angularjs).